# How can I change folder columns globally (Windows 7 & Server 2008)

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008

For some reason the column 'Folder' is showing up in all my windows when viewed in details view. Is there some way I can stop it showing for all windows?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove it and then go Tools -> Folder Options -> View -> Apply to All Folders

There is also a "Restore Defaults" button on the General tab of Folder Options.